# Using AtomicLong in a REST Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Is the atomic integer in the following piece of code shared between different REST calls? What if it was static?

```
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello Docker, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", 
        defaultValue="World") String name) {

        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
          String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is shared if the controller is a *singleton*.

Since this looks like Spring MVC *(you didn't say)*, and since a `@Controller` class by default is a singleton, then the answer is:

**Yes**, the atomic integer is shared between different REST calls.

It doesn't have to be `static`.

Comment: so if it is shared between different calls and different clients, does this mean we need to be worried about race condition inside a controller classes? I don't remember seeing any controller class use multithreading mechanisms.

Comment: You don't normally see controller classes use multi-threading mechanisms, because controller classes are almost always *stateless*. You're adding state here, but you did it right by using `AtomicLong`, which is thread-safe, so there is no multi-threading issue in your code.